# Does iOS support FTP via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios4, ftp, bluetooth, file-transfer

I know we can FTP in iOS app...not the secured channel FTP though.

I would like to know is there a way iOS can support FTP using Bluetooth?
And if is it possible to pair with Devices and consequently transfer data, which not labelled as Made for iPhone or Made for iPad?

Please let me konw. Its been days I have posted this to Apple support but not received any response from them yet.

A link from Bluetooth ORG that throws some light here 
https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/QLI_viewQDL.cfm?qid=17111

Answer (score 1):

Currently iOS does not support Bluetooth FTP profile
You will have to develop as per the MFi program to be able to write your own file exchange / transfer mechanism when communicating with non iOS device.
BEtween iOS devices you can use gamekit apis to connect and exchange data with a peer iOS device

Comment: It is very much possible for iOS using Core Foundations classes and UDP protocol... Have a look at CFWriteCreateWithFTPUrl and CFFTPStream. I have done that. What I am looking for is how this can be done on a Bluetooth com channel. But thank, your inputs MFi does help and throw some light.

Comment: I meant to say it does not support Bluetooth FTP profile, to do this custom you will need access to underlying Bluetooth protocol layer APIs which is currently not exposed

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour can be used to communicate via Bluetooth using standard tcp/udp sockets (it uses link-local addressing internally). So I would suggest you start with the Bonjour documentation. However, the application/device on the other end of the channel needs to be using Bonjour as well.

If you have no control over the remote device, i.e. it is using some other protocol, then you will need to roll this stuff yourself.

Comment: bonjour to you too